# Prove $r$-th moment of Weibull distribution

Tags: integration

Morning,

I am trying to understand how to prove the following, but a bit lost on the text books and how to decide what substitution to use.

Suppose $X$ follows the Weibull distribution with pdf

$f(x) = \beta x^{\beta -1} e^{-x\beta}$

on  x>0 with $\beta$ > 0

Show

$E(X^r) = \Gamma \left(\frac{r}{\beta} + 1\right)$

I understand substitution is used and there is no effects on the limits, but how does it happen?

I have went with $E(X^r) = \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} x^r\beta x^{\beta -1} e^{-x\beta} dx$

I make the substitution $u=x^\beta$, $du = \beta x^ {\beta -1} dx $

$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} u^{r/\beta} e^{-u} du = \Gamma \left(\frac{r}{\beta} + 1\right)$

Does this look right or has anything been missed? Or a better way to break it down in stages, its from a text book which skips out stages.

Comment: Updated with my answer, does it look right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong density function. It should be
$$
f(x)=\beta x^{\beta-1}e^{-x^\beta}, \quad x,\beta >0.
$$
There is really a scale parameter as well but it is 1 in this case. Do it like you normally do it, and then use the substitution $t=x^\beta$ and see what happens. The limits are not changed since $\beta>0$ so
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}t=0,\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}t=\infty.
$$

Edit:

**First method**

Recall the definition of the Gamma function:

$$
\Gamma(n)=\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}dx
$$
and note its resemblance to what you have (your limits of integration are a bit off: they should be from 0 to infinity). You have:
$$
E(X^r)=\int_0^\infty u^{r/\beta}e^{-u}du=\int_0^\infty u^{(r/\beta+1)-1}e^{-u}du
$$
so this is then equal to $\Gamma(r/\beta+1)$.

**Second method**

Another way is to see its connection to the Gamma distribution. The density of a Gamma($\alpha, \beta$) is
$$
f(y)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x\beta}.
$$
This is similar to what you have, with $\beta=1$ and $\alpha=\frac{r}{\beta}+1$. What we don't have is the first normalizing constant. We can multiply it and its inverse to solve that. Thus, we get:

$$
E(X^r)=\int_0^\infty u^{r/\beta}e^{-u}du=\frac{\Gamma(r/\beta+1)}{\Gamma(r/\beta+1)}\int_0^\infty u^{r/\beta}e^{-u}du\\=\Gamma(r/\beta+1)\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(r/\beta+1)}u^{r/\beta+1-1}e^{-u}du
$$
We are now integrating a complete Gamma density over its entire domain. Thus, the integral is equal to 1. What remains is
$$
E(X^r)=\Gamma\left(\frac{r}{\beta}+1\right).
$$

Comment: Updated with my answer, does it look right?

Comment: @user445714 Yes, that looks better!

Comment: Could you explain the last stage for me and how it gets to the end point, I can see how it works in my head and kinda of understand but if I had some theory it might help

Comment: @user445714 Check my post. I updated it with two ways of how to show it.

Comment: Thank you, makes so much sense when its broken down. Find it hard following text books which give no clear explanation.